# xpath and c#

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to create a winform application that searches through an XML doc.
for my search I need to convert the the XML attribute in the xpath condition to lower case, by using lower-case() xpath function.
this causes a problem related to the function namespace.

I have tried to add the namespace manualy:

```
        XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(prs.Doc.NameTable);
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("fn", "http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions");
        XmlNodeList results = prs.Doc.SelectNodes("//function[starts-with(fn:lower-case(@name),'" + txtSearch.Text + "')]",nsMgr);
```

but still I get exception:
 XsltContext is needed for this query because of an unknown function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fn:lower-case is defined in [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions). XSLT 2.0 works with XPATH 2.0.

AFAIK, .NET hasn't support XPATH 2.0 yet. and the XSLT version from .NET is 1.0 as well not 2.0 yet.

Comment: What else is possible to do in order to run a query search?

Answer (score 6):

The [`lower-case()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-lower-case) function is defined for [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/).

In [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) to convert letters to lower case one can still use the
[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-translate) function as shown below:

```
translate(@attrName, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think CodeMelt is [correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256138.aspx) and gets my +1, but perhaps the Microsoft [ms:string-compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256114.aspx) extension function (with case-insensitive option) may help solve your problem?