# Is it possible to ignore case using xpath and c#?

Tags: c#, xpath, xsd, xml-validation

Just wondered if its possible to ignore case with c# and xpath when searching an xml document?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587864

Answer (score 10):

The bad news is that Xpath is case sensitive, however there are ways to get around this.  Have a look at the following MSDN blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shjin/archive/2005/07/22/442025.aspx

Comment: No. XML Names are case sensitive. And, why quoting M$ documentation? Why not the XML specs?

Comment: @Dog Ears: Oh! I didn't see the `show-me-some-ms-documentation` tag... **;)**

Comment: He correctly states that XPath itself is case-sensitive, and then gives an MS specific solution that is perfectly applicable to the combination "C# and xpath" in the question. +1 for a good answer, what's @Alejando's objection?

Answer (score 2):

**XPath is case sensitive**.

If you would allow any case combination of characters in a name (bad decision!), an XPath expression successfully dealing with this might look like:

```
/a/b/*['anycasename' 
      = translate(name(), 
                 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                 )
      ]
```