# Using HTMLAgilityPack Extract text, which is not between tags and comes after specific node

Tags: c#, html, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

HTML code:

```
 <b> CAR </b>
    <br></br>
  Car is something you can drive.
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
```

C# code:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://website.com/x.html");

        if (doc != null)
        {
            HtmlNode link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//b[contains(text(), 'CAR')]");

            webBrowser1.DocumentText = link.InnerText;
            webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;

            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.Visible = true;
        }
```

What I manage to get:
CAR

I need to get:

CAR 
Car is something you can drive.

Any suggestions?
I have tried adding next nodes, but it I gave NullReferenceExceptions :
"//b[contains(text(), 'CAR')/br]" and "//b[contains(text(), 'CAR')/br/br]"

Thanks in advance.
PS.I Would like to avoid Regex..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPATH is case-sensitive (see here for more on this: [Is it possible to ignore case using xpath and c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313788/is-it-possible-to-ignore-case-using-xpath-and-c/4314986#4314986) ) plus the second phrase that contains 'Car' is not a child a B element. You could have it work like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://website.com/x.html");
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'car')]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

In a console application, it will output this:

```
 CAR

  Car is something you can drive.
```

Comment: Thank you Simon. Problem  with this would be if description does not contain  word "car". What if it was described. "The thing on four wheels". I have solved the problem with /following::text()[1], so code grabs CAR  and text after the node. 
 HtmlNode link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//b[contains(text(), 'CAR')]/following::text()[1]");