# Using HTMLAgilityPack to extract text which is not between tags

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

Having this source-code:

```
<div class="post_body" id="pid_103891">
   <div>
      <div class="ficha">
         <h2><span class="estado Completo">Completo</span> &quot;Bungaku Shoujo&quot; Kyou no Oyatsu: Hatsukoi</h2>
         <div class="portada" style="background-image:url('//galeria.unionfansub.com/img/Bungaku_Shoujo_portada_13419.jpg')"></div>
         <div class="datos">
            <div><strong>Fansub: </strong><a href="fansubs.php?fansub=Dekats">Dekats</a></div>
            <div><strong>Público: </strong><a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=2&amp;filtertf_publico=Shojo&amp;sortby=&amp;order=">Shojo</a></div>
            <div><strong>Ambientación: </strong><a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=2&amp;filtertf_ambientacion=Presente&amp;sortby=&amp;order=">Presente</a></div>
            <div><strong>Género: </strong><a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=2&amp;filtertf_genero=Romance&amp;sortby=&amp;order=">Romance</a>, <a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=2&amp;filtertf_contenido=Chica Magica&amp;sortby=&amp;order=">Chica Magica</a>&zwnj;, <a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=2&amp;filtertf_contenido=Vida Escolar&amp;sortby=&amp;order=">Vida Escolar</a></div>
            <div><strong>Estudio: </strong>Production I.G</div>
            <div> <span class="episodios">1</span> </div>
            <div><strong>Duración: </strong>15 min.</div>
            <div><span class="produccion">2009</span></div>
            <div><strong>Video: </strong><span class="source Blu-ray" title="Blu-ray"></span><span class="resolucion">1280x720</span> <span class="codec">H.264</span></div>
            <div><strong>Contenedor: </strong>MKV<span class="xinfo Softsubs">Softsubs</span></div>
            <div><strong>Audio: </strong><span class="flag Japones" title="Japonés AAC"></span></div>
            <div><span class="subtitulos"><span class="flag Castellano" title="Castellano"></span></span></div>
            <div><strong>Servidor: </strong><a class="host torrent" href="//torrent.unionfansub.com/details.php?id=3366&amp;hit=1" title="Torrent"></a></div>
            <div></div>
            <div id="guestalert">Solo los usuarios registrados pueden descargar por torrent</div>
            <div>
               <strong style="vertical-align:top">Archivos Torrent:</strong><span style="display:inline-block"><a style="font-size:.8em;" href="//torrent.unionfansub.com/filelist.php?id=3366" onclick="this.style.display='none';this.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].style.display='block'; return false;">[mostrar archivos]</a></span>
               <table id="filelist">
                  <tr>
                     <td>[Dekats]&nbsp;Bungaku&nbsp;Shoujo&nbsp;-&nbsp;Kyou&nbsp;no&nbsp;Oyatsu&nbsp;~Hatsukoi~&nbsp;[BD-720p]&nbsp;[3B1D8038].mkv</td>
                     <td style="text-align:right">467,93 MB</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div style="width:1em;overflow:visible;white-space:nowrap"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fforo.unionfansub.com%2Fshowthread.php?tid=4665" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="margin-top:8px;border:none; width:auto; height:2em"></iframe> <iframe src="//foro.unionfansub.com/plusone.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fforo.unionfansub.com%2Fshowthread.php?tid=4665" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0;width:84px;height:26px;"></iframe></div>
            <div>
               <hr>
               <strong>Historia principal: </strong><a href="showthread.php?tid=9726">Bungaku Shoujo</a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div><strong style="vertical-align:top">Otros Fansubs:</strong><span style="display:inline-block"><a title="Subiendo" style="display:block;" href="showthread.php?tid=15158"><span class="Subiendo"></span> AxFe <span class="flag Japonés" title="Japonés"></span></a><a title="Versión alternativa" style="display:block;" href="showthread.php?tid=6145">Osokusubs <span class="flag Japonés" title="Japonés"></span></a><a title="Versión alternativa" style="display:block;" href="showthread.php?tid=14906">Osokusubs <span class="flag Japonés" title="Japonés"></span></a></span></div>
         </div>
         <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;border-left:1px solid #AEA89C;padding-left:6px;"> </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var pass = "";
      pass = pass.substr(29).replace('&quot;', '"');
      $$('#pid_103891 .host').each(function(item) { if ((item.getAttribute('Title') != 'Torrent') && (item.getAttribute('Title') != 'XDCC') && (item.getAttribute('Title') != 'Torrent descargado')) Event.observe(item, 'click', function(event)
      {
      jd($(Event.element(event)).title, 'pid_103891', pass);
      } ); });
   </script> 
   <div></div>
   Bungaku Shoujo se centra en Konoha y Tooko, la Chica Literaria. Tooko es algo peculiar: es un yōkai que, desde pequeña, come novelas. Ahora le tocará a su compañero de club, Konoha, escribirle historias a diario para 'tenerla contenta'. Esta primera OVA (Bungaku Shoujo está compuesta de cuatro OVAs: una “suelta”, y tres pertenecientes a “Memoire”; y una película) muestra un día en el club literario, así como lo sensitiva que puede llegar a ser Tooko al “leer” una historia y cómo la Chica Literaria, al ser la líder del club literario, intenta que se una más gente al mencionado club.<br>
   <br>
   <div class="spoil">
      <h5>Capturas:</h5>
      <span class="spoilbtn" onclick="spoil(this)">Mostrar</span>
      <section>
         <div><a href="//galeria.unionfansub.com/image.php?id=13420"><span class="dimg" data-src="//galeria.unionfansub.com/mini/Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1A_13420.jpg">&quot;Bungaku Shoujo&quot; Kyou no Oyatsu: Hatsukoi - Dekats Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1A_13420</span></a><a href="//galeria.unionfansub.com/image.php?id=13421"><span class="dimg" data-src="//galeria.unionfansub.com/mini/Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1B_13421.jpg">&quot;Bungaku Shoujo&quot; Kyou no Oyatsu: Hatsukoi - Dekats Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1B_13421</span></a><a href="//galeria.unionfansub.com/image.php?id=13422"><span class="dimg" data-src="//galeria.unionfansub.com/mini/Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1C_13422.jpg">&quot;Bungaku Shoujo&quot; Kyou no Oyatsu: Hatsukoi - Dekats Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1C_13422</span></a><a href="//galeria.unionfansub.com/image.php?id=13423"><span class="dimg" data-src="//galeria.unionfansub.com/mini/Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1D_13423.jpg">&quot;Bungaku Shoujo&quot; Kyou no Oyatsu: Hatsukoi - Dekats Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1D_13423</span></a><a href="//galeria.unionfansub.com/image.php?id=13424"><span class="dimg" data-src="//galeria.unionfansub.com/mini/Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1E_13424.jpg">&quot;Bungaku Shoujo&quot; Kyou no Oyatsu: Hatsukoi - Dekats Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1E_13424</span></a><a href="//galeria.unionfansub.com/image.php?id=13425"><span class="dimg" data-src="//galeria.unionfansub.com/mini/Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1F_13425.jpg">&quot;Bungaku Shoujo&quot; Kyou no Oyatsu: Hatsukoi - Dekats Bungaku_Shoujo_OVA1F_13425</span></a></div>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to extract the text that is not within tags:

```
<div class="post_body" id="pid_103891">
   ...

   Bungaku Shoujo se centra en Konoha y Tooko, la Chica Literaria. Tooko es algo peculiar: es un yōkai que, desde pequeña, come novelas. Ahora le tocará a su compañero de club, Konoha, escribirle historias a diario para 'tenerla contenta'. Esta primera OVA (Bungaku Shoujo está compuesta de cuatro OVAs: una “suelta”, y tres pertenecientes a “Memoire”; y una película) muestra un día en el club literario, así como lo sensitiva que puede llegar a ser Tooko al “leer” una historia y cómo la Chica Literaria, al ser la líder del club literario, intenta que se una más gente al mencionado club.

   ...
</div>
```

Note that I don't know the words inside, so I suppose `text()[contains()]` can't be used.

---

What I tried:

```
MyDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='post_body']//text()[1]").InnerText
```

...similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477119/using-htmlagilitypack-extract-text-which-is-not-between-tags-and-comes-after-sp) question.

And:

```
MyDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='post_body'][1]//*[not(self::script or self::table or self::span or self::h2 or self::h5 or self::strong or self::a)]/text()").InnerText
```

or

```
MyDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='post_body'][1]//*[not(self::script or self::table or self::span or self::h2 or self::h5 or self::strong or self::a)]/text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText
```

...following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19350897/1248295) example.

Comment: if you have more than one Text node inside a `<TAG>`, you could add something like this: `var textNodes = MyDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='pid_103891']/text()").Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim());`. It's a collection of all textual parts, including the empty ones (can be used for parsing or counting. The empty parts, if any, can be easily removed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the target text is, according the HTML snippet posted above, *the only direct child text node from `post_body` that is not blank or whitespace*, you should be able use the following XPath expression to get that text:

```
var query = "//div[@class='post_body']/text()[normalize-space()]";
var result = MyDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(query).InnerText;
```

XPath breakdown:

- **`//div[@class='post_body']`**: find `div` element with class `post_body` anywhere in the document
- **`/text()`**: find all text nodes that is direct child of the `div`
- **`[normalize-space()]`**: filter out text nodes that is blank or contain whitespace(s) only

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I'm having problems when the phrase is still direct child text node but it is using <br> tags to insert line breaks. For example here: http://foro.unionfansub.com/showthread.php?tid=14243 I only get the first line (where it says: "*Hace quinientos años, la Iglesia condujo una guerra santa contra los brujos.*"), or If I use the 'SelectNodes' function I'm getting all the text but including text nodes from other divs too. Maybe could you improve your solution for this situation?.

Comment: ...even if I specify the div index like this: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='post_body'][1]/text()[normalize-space()]")` the return value include text nodes from the other divs with same class name.

Comment: I finally solved it in this way: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='post_body'][1]").SelectNodes("./text()[normalize-space()]")` but I would like to know if this can be shorten using a single XPATH query.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe there are more than 1 `div` with `class='post_body'` in the document. In this case you can try the following XPath to get text node only from the first of such `div`: `(//div[@class='post_body'])[1]/text()[normalize-space()]`